# How to recover kafka data

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am having a single node cluster kafka setup.

the docker-compose file is something like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper:3.4.9
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
        ZOO_MY_ID: 1
        ZOO_PORT: 2181
        ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zookeeper:2888:3888
    volumes:
      - zookeeper-data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - zookeeper-log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log


  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.1.1
    hostname: broker
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "PLAINTEXT://dev.kafka.org:9092"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS: 1680
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 7071
    volumes:
      - kafka-data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

For some reason I had to restart the whole kafka stack. After the restart, I found that the topics are missing.

Seems the named volume for zookeeper datalog was incorrect.

Is there a way I can recover topics data if zookeeper data was lost and kafka volume data is available?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Losing zookeeper is kind of like if your inode table was corrupt on your filesystem. There's probably some ways you could manually rebuild the data in zookeeper but it's highly unlikely to work. This is why folks run zookeeper as a highly available distributed system because it's super important to keep that data that is stored there.